# What is the name and part number for the large splash-shield item under the engine?

Tags: honda, civic, part-identification

What is the name and part number for this item protecting the undercarriage of the car on the 2013 Honda Civic EX (9th generation). It mounts under the car, and the conceals the compartment with the oil filter.

[image: Large engine splash shield]

Comment: You might try belly pan or skid plate – that's what similar ones get called on VWs.

Comment: I tried both of them first, coming from the world of Jeeps they look like skid plates but they're mostly plastic, and I wouldn't want to skid on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That part is the ["lower engine cover assembly"](http://www.hondapartsguys.com/honda/civic-coupe/74110tr3a20/2013-year/ex-trim/5-speed-manual-engine/interior-bumper-cat/under-cover-scat/?part_name=cover-assy-engine-lower):

[image]

Honda part number 74110-TR3-A20. The insert plates there are also available separately, the large part only seems to come as a full assembly:

- [Lower front engine cover P/N 74114-TR0-A00](http://www.hondapartsguys.com/honda/civic-coupe/74114tr0a00/2013-year/ex-trim/5-speed-manual-engine/interior-bumper-cat/under-cover-scat/?part_name=plate-fr-engine-cover-lower) (not in your picture, it's the more angular insert)
- [Lower rear engine cover P/N 74115-TR3-A20](http://www.hondapartsguys.com/honda/civic-coupe/74115tr3a20/2013-year/ex-trim/5-speed-manual-engine/interior-bumper-cat/under-cover-scat/?part_name=plate-rr-engine-cover-lower) (the rounded metal insert plate)

Comment: Does `74110-TR3-A20` come with all the insert plates and screws too?

Comment: @EvanCarroll It comes with everything shown in the image. If you check the ["under cover"](http://www.hondapartsguys.com/auto-parts/2013/honda/civic-coupe/ex-trim/5-speed-manual-engine/interior-bumper-cat/under-cover-scat/) page on that site you can get individual parts. You may have to order [a few new clips too](http://www.hondapartsguys.com/honda/civic-coupe/91503sz5003/2013-year/ex-trim/5-speed-manual-engine/interior-bumper-cat/under-cover-scat/?part_name=clip-bumper-face) (91503-SZ5-003), and also it looks like there's a bolt, item #18 on the under cover page, can't tell if it's included.

Comment: Yea, finding out what's included is also fun. It seems like everything in the box would be included but I've found that's not often the case. Manufacture part guides are always surprise fun.

Comment: Well, I can say, those bumper clips would probably be *really* handy to have around whether you need them now or not, ha. You don't want to be like me; there are so many cable ties through hastily drilled holes holding my Prelude together right now I lost track of where they are.

Comment: I wish I could buy a box of spare body screws bolts, and parts. It's amazing you can't do that for cars but you can for Ikea.

Comment: @EvanCarroll [Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/30Pcs-Nylon-Rivet-Push-Type-Trim-Clip-Retainer-for-GM-Honda-91503-sz5-003-/291614499556?hash=item43e59422e4:g:RKYAAOSwgQ9VqTG2&vxp=mtr) sometimes pulls through, and salvage yards (I make a point to pick up parts that I know I'll need to replace some day if they have a good price, since it's getting harder and harder to find parts for my car).