# Is it possible to repair the lower engine cover assembly?

Tags: repair, plastic

Has anyone ever successfully repair [this part](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/32979/999) with epoxy, or a heat gun (melting the plastic) or anything that lasts? Mine is pretty screwed up, but it seems like a relatively insignificant part.

I believe this part is also called colloquially *skid plate*, *belly cover*, *splash guard*, or *wind plate*.

Here are some more pictures of it all broken:

[image: tears]
[image: broken tabs]
[image: more tears]

Comment: I think I would try some aluminum strips (you could go pretty thin 1 or 2 mm would probably do it) on both sides and use pop rivets to secure them. I've had mixed results with epoxies on plastic parts.

Comment: @dlu - Those aren't bad suggestions. My take is "yes" you can fix this ... is it worth your time? I guess if you're flat broke it could be worth it, but otherwise getting a new one is going to do much better.

Comment: Or get a used one… I often find some pleasure in repairing something rather than creating more junk in the world, but I agree – one way or another the cost-benefit analysis should come out in your favor.

Comment: If you don't care that much how it looks go the drifter's way and use zip-ties.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing, haha I think I know what you're getting at, the ol zip tie frankenstein stitches. Good call

Comment: Clean and sand surfaces then liberally apply GFlex... http://www.westsystem.com/ss/g-flex-epoxy/

Answer (score 1):

Not with the methods you mention.

Drilling holes in it either side of a split and using cable ties is a good way to repair it. Leave at least an inch of distance from the split so there is enough plastic for strength.

Glue/epoxy/etc won't last 5 minutes.